# selecting a value from the dropdown and it should be displayed in <a> tag

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

[When i click on 'a' tag dropdrown appears now i want to select a option and that option should be displayed on "choose a specialty", like if i select fever then fever should be displayed. how to implement this

```html
<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="panel-group">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
 
 
 
      <a style="text-decoration : none" href="#collapse1" data-toggle="collapse">
        <h5 class="text-muted" >&nbsp; &nbsp; Specialty</h5>
        <h4>&nbsp; &nbsp;Choose a specialty ;<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span>
        </h4>
      </a>
      <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
     <div class="list-group">
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Fever</a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Dentist</a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Injury</a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Foot</a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Xray</a>
</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wh6zs.jpg)

Comment: your pic - is that what you are currently getting or the desired result? cos it's what i'm getting now (with current code) http://jsbin.com/genuneloxi/edit?html,output

Comment: i am currently getting .my desired result is the selected value should be displayed in h4

Comment: So why don't you add h4 tags?